# Car electronics not working / No start

Tags: electrical

All happened when negative metal touched postive on the battery with the negative on the other side. .

won't work

Fuel pump

Electric widows 
Dashboard lights 
No horn
No hazards

Car won't start

Please help

Battery and fuses are fine

Comment: I bet your probably just missing a blown main fuse somewhere. Whats year/model?

Comment: 2006 chev aveo 1.5  Sohc